# Not sure how to properly perform this SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am migrating data from an old, non-relational, database over into a new, relational, database structure.  I am currently at a spot where I don't know how to properly process the data I am trying to insert into one of my data tables.

Essentially I have the following two tables:

```
Table: Contact
    Contact_ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
    First_Name VARCHAR(50) NULL
    Last_Name VARCHAR(50) NULL
    Company_ID INT NOT NULL

Table: Contact_Fax
    Contact_ID INT NOT NULL
    Fax_Num VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    In_User BIT NOT NULL
```

Now the tables are setup this way so that we can easily manage a Contact getting a second Fax number, or getting a new Fax number while we retain the old information in case we need it for something.

The table I am pulling data from has it's data laid out like so:

```
Table: Company
    Company_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    Contant VARCHAR(100) NULL
    Address VARCHAR(100) NULL
    City VARCHAR(100) NULL
    Phone1 VARCHAR(20) NULL
    Phone2 VARCHAR(20) NULL
    Fax VARCHAR(20) NULL
```

Now I've been able to put together CSV Files to hold the data I need, each of them having the specific columns to match up with the tables I will be importing into:

```
CSV: Contact
    First_Name
    Last_Name
    Company

CSV: Contact_Fax
    First_Name
    Last_Name
    Company
    Fax
```

I have no problem grabbing the data from either CSV files and putting them into Temp Tables for me to use to insert into the actual database tables.  However for my Fax Table, when I went to insert the data from the Temp table into the actual one, not all of the data got transmitted.  This was my SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Contact_Fax
SELECT Contact_ID, Fax, 1
FROM Con_Fax_Temp
INNER JOIN Contact ON Contact.First_Name = Con_Fax_Temp.First_Name
INNER JOIN Company ON Company.Company_Name = Con_Fax_Temp.Company_Name
WHERE Contacts.Company_ID = Company.Company_ID
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here are some example of the data in the CSV Files:

```
CSV: Contact
    Mike,Langtry,LANGTRY BLAST TECHNOLOGIES INC.
    Adrian,Stickland,Main,Connect Tech Inc
    Todd,Corley,Main,Takata Seat Belts

CSV: Contact_Fax
    Mike,Langtry,LANGTRY BLAST TECHNOLOGIES INC.,9056812814
    Adrian,Stickland,Connect Tech Inc,5198364878
    Todd,Corley,Takata Seat Belts,6147663628
```

EDIT2: So I am horrible as describing what it is I am trying to accomplish.

I am trying to insert data from my `Contact_Fax` CSV into the `Contact_Fax` table.  Now the `Con_Fax_Temp` table I have mentioned above in my SQL looks like so:

```
Table: Con_Fax_Temp
    First_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    Last_Name VARCHAR(50) NULL
    Company_Name VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL
    Fax VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
```

My goal is to insert each record of my CSV into my `Contact_Fax` table, using the `Contact_ID` column of the `Contact` table as a foreign key.  To check that I have the correct Foreign Key value I want to compare the values of the `First_Name` and `Company_Name` columns in the `Con_Fax_Temp` table with the `First_Name` and `Company_ID` columns in the `Contact` Table.

**Note:** The `Contact` table has the foreign key `Company_ID` which is why I had the Join on the `Company` table so that I can reference the `Company_Name` associated with each `Company_ID`

I hope I am explaining this a bit better >_<

Comment: Can you include the contents of those tables? It's more than likely something with your join clause, but without seeing the data (or at very least what is or is not being inserted) there's no way to say for sure.

Comment: @Xedni There are hundreds of records in the tables, so I can't put in all of it, but I will edit the OP with an example of a few lines of data

Comment: I understand. Maybe include a handful of rows; say 1-2 that ARE working and 1-2 that are NOT.

Comment: Maybe what you really need is left joins? And you should move your where predicate to the join instead of the where clause. And what happens when you have more than 1 Mike, Todd or Adrian? Joining only on first name is extremely brittle.

Comment: @SeanLange That might be my problem, I can give it a try

Comment: @SeanLange Just saw your edit.  I am trying to have it grab by the first name, but check the first name with the company name.  That's what I am trying, and apparently failing to do.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about checking the first name with the company name. There is something missing here but I can't figure out quite what. For sure the data structures seem to be a bit less than optimal. And we don't see a definition for the CON_FAX_TEMP table. I think you need to look closely at your question and post all of the tables definitions. Some sample data as inserts would be a huge help also.

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry, I am occasionally horrible at describing what I am trying to do.  I am trying to insert into the `Contact_Fax` table, and trying to reference the `Contact_ID` value from the `Contacts` table as a foreign key.  And to make sure I am getting the correct ID I am trying to match up the First Name, and Company Name of each `Contact_ID` with the values in the temp table.  I'll add this to the OP

Comment: @SeanLange Hopefully my edit makes what I am trying to accomplish make more sense.

Comment: Matching on First_Name and Company is a horrible idea. You are doing inner join on Names which explains that if your have them spell differently in 2 different tables will not give you all the records. There could also be extra spaces or hidden characters that will not  match up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in the comments you seem to have some pretty sketchy architecture here. And the join logic you have is incredibly brittle. What happens if you have more than 1 Todd in a company? Joining on names like that is highly likely to break at some point.

But if I understand what you are trying to do (logic concerns aside), your query would look something like this. Notice I specified the columns for the insert. You should ALWAYS do this. Also, I included the table alias for every column so you know exactly which table each data point is coming from.

```
INSERT INTO Contact_Fax
(
    Contact_ID
    , Fax_Num
    , In_User
)
SELECT con.Contact_ID
    , cft.Fax
    , 1
FROM Con_Fax_Temp cft
INNER JOIN Company c ON c.Company_Name = cft.Company_Name
INNER JOIN Contact con ON con.First_Name = cft.First_Name
                    AND con.Company_Name = cft.Company_Name
                    AND con.Company_ID = c.Company_ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)  I understand the logic concerns of what I am doing, but I was trying to do this quick, as opposed to smart, which I guess ended up being my problem.

Comment: Sometimes we have to work with brittle stuff...especially when dealing with external data. Glad this solved your issue.